# Rgbdslam crahes with Exit code -6

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey i am using the GUI version of the rgbdslam. It worked fine earlier but now i am getting a wierd problem .

Whenever i start the node it crashes and gives out the following error.

```
    Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40801) with this library (version 0x40804)
    ================================================================================
REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-1] has died!
    process has died [pid 3190, exit code -6, cmd /home/karan/ros_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/bin/rgbdslam __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/home/karan/.ros/log/14bc0f78-aca3-11e2-bff4-8ca9824e2ee4/rgbdslam-1.log].
    log file: /home/karan/.ros/log/14bc0f78-aca3-11e2-bff4-8ca9824e2ee4/rgbdslam-1*.log
    Initiating shutdown!
    ================================================================================
```

The headless launch file works fine and i am able to register frames via service calls. So the problem is only GUI related.

It kind of is a problem of the Qt library having 2 versions installed on my system.
How can i solve this problem. Any help would be apprecaited.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61457/rgbdslam-crahes-with-exit-code--6/) by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 263 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, not sure how to solve this, but here are some ideas:

Maybe your compiler/linker uses another qt version than what is loaded at runtime? Find out what rgbdslam is compiled with (`make VERBOSE=1`) and linked against (`ldd bin/rgbdslam|grep Q`).

Maybe you need to adjust the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH by adding the path of the correct Qt or putting it in front of the "incorrect" path.
Or see if you can adapth the settings in CMakeLists.txt (the line "find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED"?) to use the other Qt version.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0